# How to insert a clickable and fixed background

Tags: css, custom-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix clickable background with Wordpress theme and CSS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77004/how-to-fix-clickable-background-with-wordpress-theme-and-css)

I have a problem using a clickable adverting skin as background of my website. My site is this: http://www.tvindiretta.com. If you scroll down any page of my site you will see that the top of the background si notte fixed but float and mess all up... I think that I should add a white background in foreground. I really need your help, I'm a noob in CSS and programming.... I read about this parameters googling for...

```
  display: block; ??
  text-indent: px; ??
  overflow: hidden; ??
  z-index:22 ???
```

...but I don't know how to solve this problem... Here is my Wordpress theme CSS file http://www.tvindiretta.com/wp-content/themes/videoplus/style.css Thanks a LOT for any help in advance

P.S. This site: IMPRONTALAQUILA.ORG in certain pages shows the same ad and also other similar skins without any bug or problem... how can I get the same result? I want the background to be fixed so that users see it browsing any part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Add div after body tag and apply below style. Your site start working.

```
 <div class="fixedHeader"></div>
<style type="text/css">
.fixedHeader{
    position: fixed;
    height: 80px;
    background: white url(http://www.affiliago.it/accounts/default1/banners/SKIN_BAKECA.jpg) no-repeat no-repeat center top;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
}
</style>
```